# Which is more grammatical : 'the feeling is not x, it is y' or 'the feeling not x is actually y'?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-structure

> As shown above, he misses someone mysterious, whoever that is, which
>   confirms to us that the feeling **is** not happiness nor depression, **it is emptiness.**

It is a sentence from an essay my friend wrote, and I don't think putting "it is emptiness" without any coordinating conjunction would be seriously wrong, but he was saying things like independent clause and dependent clause so I could not quite get him. The one I suggested him was this:

> As shown above, he misses someone mysterious, whoever that is, which
>   confirms to us that the feeling not happiness nor depression **is actually emptiness**.

But he said it is not very grammatical. Which one of these sentences is correct then?

Comment: The original sentence is much better.

Comment: I would write ". . . someone mysterious, whoever it may be; which confirms to us that what he feels is neither happiness nor depression but emptiness." But I don't see that this can be inferred from his missing someone mysterious; I suspect that either *mysterious* or *emptiness* is not quite the word you want--perhaps both words.

Answer (score 4):

Your friend's sentence is perfectly grammatical, although not entirely intelligible—it's sort of mysterious itself!

This sort of construction without a conjunction is permissible, licensed by the contrasting of negative and positive: "It is not A, it is B."

Your own sentence, however, is not English.

- In the first place, *not A nor B* is not an idiomatic construction: you need either *neither A nor B* or *not A or B*.
- In the second place, there is nothing to link *not happiness or depression* with *the feeling*: you need *the feeling **is** not happiness or depression*.
- Finally, having built the first part of this section with *is* you must either start a new clause with *it is*, or conjoin *emptiness* with *not happiness or depression* so it shares a subject and verb with that conjunct term; the proper conjunction would be *but*.

> ... the feeling is not happiness or depression, it is emptiness.
>   ... the feeling is not happiness or depression but emptiness.

Comment: I know I'm [necroing](https://www.wordnik.com/words/necro) this - I came across the title in the sidebar and thought to close it, but it turned out to be an interesting question. If we fixed the neither/nor problem, couldn't we grammatically say "the feeling, neither happiness nor depression, is actually emptiness." ?